# Can't retrieve Appointment.StartTimeZone through EWS Managed API on Exchange 2007 SP1

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I can retrieve the `Appointment.TimeZone` for items with:

```
PropertySet propertiesAll = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ..., AppointmentSchema.TimeZone, AppointmentSchema.StartTimeZone, ...);
ServiceResponseCollection<ServiceResponse> response = Exchange.LoadPropertiesForItems(items, propertiesAll);
```

But not `Appointment.StartTimeZone` which returns null.

`Appointment.TimeZone` is string and seems to be comparable to `DisplayName` of `TimeZoneInfo` objects, but unfortunately this seems to be in the language of the end users (in our environment I encountered different languages returned by Exchange for different appointments). So it seems to be complicated/impossible to make proper use of `TimeZone` string for an appointment.

The main question is, what could result `StartTimeZone` of an appointment to be null?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, Exchange 2007 SP1 does not support the StartTimeZone property of EWS. If you want to use that property, you must use Exchange 2010.

Sorry I couldn't be of any more help