# Exchange Web Services, unable to set startTimeZone of appointment (java api)

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007

When trying to set the start time zone of an appointment (in ews java API 1.1.5) I get an error. I'm trying to set the time zone because an exception is raised when using appointment.setStart otherwise.

```
Appointment = new Appointment(service);

appointment.setStartTimeZone(new TimeZoneDefinition() {{setId("what should go hère")}});

appointment.setStart(startTime);....
```

Using exchange 2007

Comment: Your answer may be in another thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133625/problem-retrieving-appointment-starttimezone-through-ews-managed-api-on-exchange  Also i would recommend using the SOAP API if you continue to have issues with the managed API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It finally appear that the JAVA EWS API is a bad (and full of bugs) port of the C# version.
So the rule is simply to not use it.

There is some alternative out there :

[J-xchange](http://sourceforge.net/projects/j-xchange/)

For my specific question, it looks like  setStartTimeZone function expect a C# object, which it's not possible to get.

Comment: I have to agree. Maybe this has changed in version 2 which has been open sourced at github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api but it seems to remain broken: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/1317af95-146c-4540-9bec-1b8eed6790dc/how-to-get-time-zone-id-from-attendeeavailability-using-ews-api-20?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get around this by commenting out the validation code regarding StartTimeZone (lines 247-256 of Appointment.java) and recompiling the jar.  If I pass in date/times based on UTC, the appointment gets created in the user's timezone.